# SwiftUI : Segue navigation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass data from one screen to another, is it possible to create segue in swiftUI and use below method?

`prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Comment: For sort answer for your question is No. It's impossible in SwiftUI because SwiftUI doesn't use segue to transition between controllers, you can use `NavigationButton(destination:)` instead

Comment: I can't imagine there is no way to create custom transitions. That would be nuts. @TungVuDuc

Comment: @LinusGeffarth: @Tung Vu Duc didn’t say you can not use transitions.. just that UIStoryboardSegue is not an option in SwiftUI as this is a UIKit concept. In SwiftUI you do custom transitions by adding a modifier to the view you are presenting `Text(“hi”).transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .slide))`

Comment: Thanks for the hint @mimo, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you with the segue issue, but if you want pass data from one screen to another you can do in this way:

First: create a var in your destination

```
struct DestinationView : View {
    let information: InfoType
    var body: some View { ... }
}
```

Then when you pass this info inside your navigation button:

```
NavigationButton(destination: DestinationView(information: info)) {
     Text("click me")
}
```

Sorry for not answering exactly what you want, but hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is where @ObjectBinding comes in.  If you wish to pass data from view A to view B, you would use @ObjectBinding on a struct or a class, have that struct or class conform to BindableObject with declaring a didChange property and by using Combine, publish those changes to your view via @ObjectBindable property wrapper if changes are made. Otherwise this will allow you to have a referenced-link to your object.